# Flutter "[Fatal Error] kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.30.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog." Error

Tags: java, flutter, kotlin, dart

When I add any dependancy in my flutter project and it resolve dependancy completely no error
but when I run the app it give this error
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[Fatal Error] kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.30.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.30.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.30.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.30.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':shared_preferences_android:generateDebugRFile'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':shared_preferences_android:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.5.30.
> Required by:
> project :shared_preferences_android > org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.5.30
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.5.30.
> > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.5.30/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.30.pom
> > Content is not allowed in prolog.
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.5.30.
> > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.5.30/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.30.pom
> > Content is not allowed in prolog.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Please help me to resolve such an error